# MSSQL SQLSRV PHP Query from SQL View

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, php-7, sqlsrv

I am trying to query data from MS SQL 2008 server. I am querying data from a **SQL View**. Not a SQL table.

Does anyone know if **SQLSRV** is able to query a View from SQL Server?

Sample code below. Works when I use a **Table** but not when using a **SQL View**.

I am using PHP Version 7 along with MS SQL 2008 R2.

**Connection**

```
$serverName = "LOC-SVR\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName","UID" => "svc_test","PWD" => "test");
$connect = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

**Query Code**

```
$sql = "SELECT Col1
             , Col2
             , Col3 
        FROM V_TEST_VIEW;"; 

sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0);

sqlsrv_query($connect,$sql);

$res = sqlsrv_query($connect, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));  

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
          echo $row['Col1'];
          echo $row['Col2'];
          echo $row['Col3'];
        }
```

**Result**

There is no Error. Only 1 row is returned from the view. In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, few hundred rows are returned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use View whith MS SQL PostgreSQL and MYSQL and the Views after createad are treated as tabels. The only diference it's how you create them, alterate them and destroy them.

Comment: Where is the code for your created  view?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php

I am able to query my View using this.

**CODE**

```
$sql = "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM V_TEST_VIEW";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connect, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Retrieve each row as an object.
// Because no class is specified, each row will be retrieved as a stdClass object.
// Property names correspond to field names.
while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt)) {
  echo "<strong>".$obj->Col1."</strong>, ".$obj->Col2 ."<br />";
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably about cursor type `SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET `.